# Async/Await with setTimeout works well but not with custom delay

Tags: javascript, async-await

When I run an example that I found on the internet which uses setTimeout, it works fine. But when I replace setTimeout with a long running for loop the output appears after delay. Do we have to use a factory made asynchronous function all the time?

Original code:

```
const doSomethingAsync = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('I did something'), 3000)})
        }

    const doSomething = async () => {
        console.log(await doSomethingAsync())
    }
console.log('Before')
doSomething()
console.log('After')
```

Code with custom delay:

```
const doSomethingAsync = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        for(let i=0;i<4000000000;i++){}
        resolve("I did something!");
        })
        }

    const doSomething = async () => {
        console.log(await doSomethingAsync())
    }
console.log('Before')
doSomething()
console.log('After')
```

When the custom code runs the output of After happens after the delay, whereas in the original code After appears immediately.

Edit: By the way the question at [Why isn't Javascript async function immediately returning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086423/why-isnt-javascript-async-function-immediately-returning) is similar but the order doesn't change in my case, timing does.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded - never busy wait. The `Promise` constructor's executor will also immediately be called, so your giant loop blocks everything.

Comment: That`s not a "custom delay". That's a blocking loop ...

Comment: I understand, but my question is how to create the same behavior without setTimeout which uses plain Javascript (and hopefully is easy to understand)

Comment: It is irrelevant that the order doesn't change in your question. The essence of the linked question is the same. `async`/`await` doesn't make the loop run in a different thread, so it is completely useless when have code that is blocking the thread (like a long running loop). If you have a valid reason to block the thread, you should look into Workers (as suggested by the answer in the linked page).

Comment: Question is actually simple: how can I write a setTimeout function with vanilla Javascript. V8 etc implementations (as far as I know) uses c libraries. I hope the answer is not we cannot. Then we're stuck with provided functions.

Comment: Without context it's really hard to answer that. There already exists a `setTimeout` function. You're using it in your frist example. It accepts a function that will be scheduled to run after the given time has passed (and the thread isn't occupied). If you want to block the thread, you could use an endless loop, though that rarely ever makes sense and wastes a lot of resources. Not to mention that it blocks all other JavaScript from running. There really aren't any more flavors. What is it you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I think no special context required. I'm trying to identify the mechanics of asynchronous function calls. By definition a function should yield other functions if at some point it takes too long (without cpu load) for the function to return. Now the setTimeout simulates that behaviour but what if I write an actual function (let's call A) and while it works, do something else (B) when A is idle for some reason. Actually all the answers avoiding my simple question: Can you recreate a setTimeout function or not?

Comment: Ok never mind, same question had been asked before at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501356/how-to-create-your-own-settimeout-function but no useful answer there either. My conclusion is async/await can be used only with functions provided by the wizards of JS

Comment: You might be interested in [Concurrency model and the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Comment: Thanks Ivar, so setTimeout puts the message later in the queue, but edited code runs the blocking part immediately. that's why there's timing difference.

Comment: @S.A.Koroglu Indeed.